# What is the cause of OutOfMemoryError in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I'm only just starting to learn Scala, coming from Python. I was attempting a basic file processing task in Scala. The task is to remove substrings like `"[ ... ]"` from data files using regex. The script successfully processes the first few files and then throws a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` error. The data file at which the error occurs is about 70MB, and I have 16GB of RAM at my disposal. (The preceding 6 files have filesize < 100Kb, with the first one as an exception: 5.5MB).

My question is: **what causes the** `OutOfMemoryError`, **and how can I change my approach to prevent it from happening?** I don't understand why it happens. I have little experience in debugging memory errors, as Python is relatively forgiving in memory management.

Any additional comments on coding style or the methods I use are more than welcome - I am eager to learn.

**Regexer.scala:**

```
import scala.io.Source 
import java.io._

object Regexer {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val filenames = Source.fromFile("all_files.txt").getLines()

    for (fn <- filenames) {

        val datafile:String = Source.fromFile(fn).mkString

        val new_data:String = datafile.replaceAll(raw"\[.*?\]", "")

        val file = new File(fn)         
        val bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))
        bw.write(new_data)
        bw.close()


    }   
  } 
}
```

`all_files.txt` is a file containing paths to all files to process (as they are located in subdirectories).

Finally, the complete error message thrown upon execution:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:596)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:190)
    at scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder.appendAll(StringBuilder.scala:249)
    at scala.io.BufferedSource.mkString(BufferedSource.scala:97)
    at Regexer$$anonfun$main$1.apply(Regexer.scala:12)
    at Regexer$$anonfun$main$1.apply(Regexer.scala:10)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at Regexer$.main(Regexer.scala:10)
    at Regexer.main(Regexer.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$$anonfun$run$1.apply(ScalaClassLoader.scala:70)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:101)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:70)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:101)
    at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner$class.run(ObjectRunner.scala:22)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.run(ObjectRunner.scala:39)
    at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner$class.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:29)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:39)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:65)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.run$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:87)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:98)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:103)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

Comment: The problem is using `mkString`. It seems like making that large of a file into a string all at once is causing the error. Trying reading line by line instead.

Comment: I changed my code to read and write line-by-line and that solved it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might have 16Gib on your computer, but that doesn't mean the JVM can use all of that.  Scala code (normally) runs in the Java Virtual Machine (JVM), which has its own memory.  The default amount of memory you have available might be too low for your program.  The maximum available memory for you process can be set with the `-Xmx` option.  Try something like `java -Xmx1024m Regexer` or `java -Xmx2g Regexer` or however much memory you think should work.  If you still get the problem after adding upping the available memory needed to process the files, then you either have some memory leak going on, or your algorithm needs to be optimized.

In your specific case, instead of loading the entire file into memory, consider processing line by line, or some other buffer amount, so that at any time you only need to keep a small portion of the file in memory

Comment: Upping the RAM available to the JVM didn't help. I changed the code to read and write line-by-line and that solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: @TBZ92 Just want to make sure, but what was the exact command you used?  The way to do it would be `java -Xmx2048m MyClass` for example, `java MyClass -Xmx2048m` would pass the parameter to your code, instead of the JVM.  That being said, in your case, avoiding a full file read is probably a good idea either way, no reason to use more memory than needed.

Comment: Exactly, it's a better approach in every way. It's the kind of mind set change I need to start writing good Scala. I used `scala MyClass -Xmx13g`, ranging from 2-13Gigs. I'm surprised it didn't work, maybe the OS doesn't allow the JVM to allocate that much RAM to itself (I didn't notice any increase in RAM usage when running the erroneous script).

Comment: As I said doing it that was passes the parameter to you program instead of the JVM so in reality you were still using the default max heap size.  If you are using the scala command instead of the java command to run your code, you would need to write `scala -J-Xmx2g MyClass` or add the `-Xmx2g` option to the `JAVA_OPTS`  environment variable.

Comment: Wow, yeah, that was a dumb mistake. Thanks for pointing that one out!

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to load the file completely

```
val datafile:String = Source.fromFile(fn).mkString //this should be the culprit.
```

Also try to increase the heap size of the JVM in case processing line by line is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

To add to puhlen answer, you can read a file line by line with :

```
import scala.io.Source
for(line <- Source.fromPath("myfile.txt").getLines())
```